# Have another if option in the for loop in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

I have this functioning For /F loop:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (New.txt) do (
    echo "%%A" | findstr /C:"[B]" 1>nul
    if !errorlevel!==1 echo "%%A"
    set line=%%A
    if !errorlevel!==0 echo BOLD !line:[B]=!
)
```

What it does is type out lines in a text file, except if it coms across a line with the text `[B]` in it, it adds `BOLD` to the start of the line. I'm looking for a way to have something similar for `[S]` where it can add `SUPER` to the begining. I had this:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (New.txt) do (
        echo "%%A" | findstr /C:"[B]" 1>nul
        if !errorlevel!==1 echo "%%A" | findstr /C:"[S]" 1>nul & if %errorlevel%==1 echo "%%A" & if %errorlevel%==0 echo SUPER !line:[S]=!
        set line=%%A
        if !errorlevel!==0 echo "!line:[B]=!"
    )
```

However it does not work because of how that is running.

**EDIT: I cannot end the loop with a break or goto because there are multiple lines to process.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using DelayedExpansion I'd always stuff the current line into variable `line` and check via string substitution if `line` contains the markup.

```
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (New.txt) do (
    set "line=%%A"
    if "!line!" neq "!line:[B]=!" set "line=BOLD !line:[B]=!"
    if "!line!" neq "!line:[S]=!" set "line=SUPER !line:[S]=!"
    echo=!line!
)
```

Comment: Intriguing. I hadn't considered using variable commands. It seems like that would work very well. Thanks.

Comment: As always, LotPings the batch expert to the rescue! :D